# Unable to have proper C++ template deduction working (C++17)

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++17

I'm unable to have this code running properly on Ubuntu 20.04 (gcc), and I'm only able to have the template deducted for the else branch (integers), ignoring all the deductions for bool, double and std:string

I even tried the std::enable_if but to no avail...

What am I'm missing here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

namespace myns
{
    using UInt64 = uint64_t;
    using Int64 = int64_t;
    using UInt32 = uint32_t;
    using Int32 = int32_t;
    using UInt16 = uint16_t;
    using Int16 = int16_t;
    using UInt8 = uint8_t;
    using Int8 = int8_t;
}

bool function_int (myns::UInt64& i)
{
    i = 10;
}

bool function_float (double& d)
{
    d = 4.3;
}

bool function_bool (bool& b)
{
    b = true;
}

bool function_str(std::string& s)
{
    s = "Hello World";
}

template <typename T>
bool function(T&& value)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, bool>)
    {
        std::cout << "Returning bool" << std::endl;
        return function_bool (std::forward<T> (value));
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
    {
        std::cout << "Returning double" << std::endl;
        return function_float (std::forward<T> (value));
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
    {
        std::cout << "Returning string" << std::endl;
        return function_str (std::forward<T> (value));
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Returning integer" << std::endl;
        myns::UInt64 val;
        auto ret = function_int (val);
        
        value = val;
    }
}

using namespace myns;

int main()
{
    UInt64 ui64;
    Int64  i64;
    UInt32 ui32;
    Int32  i32;
    UInt16 ui16;
    Int16  i16;
    UInt8  ui8;
    Int8  i8;
    
    std::string str;
    bool boolean;
    double dbl;
    
    function(str);
    function(ui64);
    function(i64);
    function(ui32);
    function(i32);
    function(ui16);
    function(i16);
    function(ui8);
    function(i8);
    
    function(boolean);
    function(dbl);
    
    std::cout << "Uint64: " << ui64 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Int64: " << i64 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "UInt32: " << ui32 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Int32: " << i32 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "UInt16: " << ui16 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Int16: " << i16 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "UInt8: " << ui8 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Int8: " << i8 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "String: " << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bool: " << boolean << std::endl;
    std::cout << "double: " << dbl << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Returning integer
Returning integer
Returning integer
Returning integer
Returning integer
Returning integer
Returning integer
Returning integer
Returning integer
Returning integer
Returning integer
Uint64: 10
Int64: 10
UInt32: 10
Int32: 10
UInt16: 10
Int16: 10
UInt8: 

Int8: 

String: 

bool: 1
double: 10
```

I've been banging my head for almost a day with no solutions on site, I even though of giving up and creating a template specialization for all the types, but I this is a lot of code "repetition" that could be all done in a small template

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `T` in those cases is a reference (e.g. `double &`).  `std::is_same_v<double &, double>` is indeed false. Try `std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>, double>` for example.

Comment: Oh man... The number of hours I missed with this thing :D ;D

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer... not sure why I made it a comment in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is being deduced as a reference here.  For example, when invoked with a double, the argument is `double & &&` (which collapses to `double &`).  `T` is `double &`, which is not the same thing as `double`.  `std::is_same_v<double &, double>` is indeed false.

One solution would be to remove any reference from `T` before checking:

```
std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>, double>
```

---

Side note: you have several functions returning `bool` but without any `return` statement. This causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Well I did it like in my answer below, and it also worked.. :D

Comment: And yeah… this was a fast prototyping code that I got from the real project code just o get an example over here!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cdhowie the proper code should be like the one below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

namespace myns
{
    using UInt64 = uint64_t;
    using Int64 = int64_t;
    using UInt32 = uint32_t;
    using Int32 = int32_t;
    using UInt16 = uint16_t;
    using Int16 = int16_t;
    using UInt8 = uint8_t;
    using Int8 = int8_t;
}

bool function_int (myns::UInt64& i)
{
    i = 10;
}

bool function_float (double& d)
{
    d = 4.3;
}

bool function_bool (bool& b)
{
    b = true;
}

bool function_str(std::string& s)
{
    s = "Hello World";
}

template <typename T>
bool function(T&& value)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>, bool>)
    {
        std::cout << "Returning bool" << std::endl;
        return function_bool (std::forward<T> (value));
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>, double>)
    {
        std::cout << "Returning double" << std::endl;
        return function_float (std::forward<T> (value));
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>, std::string>)
    {
        std::cout << "Returning string" << std::endl;
        return function_str (std::forward<T> (value));
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Returning integer" << std::endl;
        myns::UInt64 val;
        auto ret = function_int (val);
        
        value = val;
        return value;
    }
}

using namespace myns;

int main()
{
    UInt64 ui64;
    Int64  i64;
    UInt32 ui32;
    Int32  i32;
    UInt16 ui16;
    Int16  i16;
    UInt8  ui8;
    Int8  i8;
    
    std::string str;
    bool boolean;
    double dbl;
    
    // Ignore the return values, this is just for prototyping..
    function(str);
    function(ui64);
    function(i64);
    function(ui32);
    function(i32);
    function(ui16);
    function(i16);
    function(ui8);
    function(i8);
    
    function(boolean);
    function(dbl);
    
    std::cout << "Uint64: " << ui64 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Int64: " << i64 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "UInt32: " << ui32 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Int32: " << i32 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "UInt16: " << ui16 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Int16: " << i16 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "UInt8: " << ui8 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Int8: " << i8 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "String: " << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bool: " << boolean << std::endl;
    std::cout << "double: " << dbl << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: As cdhowie noted, you are missing a whole bunch of return statements.  Perhaps you intended these functions to have a return type of `void` instead of `bool`?

Comment: This won't work when calling `function` with an rvalue reference, though. `T` will be `double` in that case. If you want it to work for rvalue and lvalue references (perfect forwarding) then you need the `std::remove_reference_t` approach.

Comment: I'm aware, this was just a prototype, in the real code there's actually a need for the return values... I just wanted a quick code to show how I could instantiate the templates and deduct the types...

Comment: I'm editing the answer to have the proper std::remove_reference_t